# why does my program on mergesort trigger a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

```
#include<stdio.h>
void merge(int a[],int left[],int l,int right[],int r){
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
while(i<l&&j<r){
    if(left[i]<=right[j]){
        a[k]=left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    else{
        a[k]=right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
while(i<l){
    a[k]=left[i];
    k++;
    i++;
   }
while(j<r){
    a[k]=right[j];
    k++;
    j++;
  }
}
void mergesort(int a[],int s,int n){
int i;
int mid=(s+n)/2;
int left[mid],right[n-mid];

if(n<2) return;

else{

    for(i=s;i<mid;i++){
        left[i]=a[i];
    }
    for(i=mid;i<n;i++){
        right[i]=a[i];
    }
    mergesort(left,s,mid);
    mergesort(right,n-mid,n);
    merge(a,left,mid,right,n-mid);
   }
 }
int main(int argv,char*argc){
int a[]={9,8,7,5,1,2,4,3,6},i;
printf("sorting....");
mergesort(a,0,9);
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}
return 1;
}
```

the program terminates before givin the output...pls help..
the logic was taken from [mycodeschool.org](http://www.mycodeschool.com/work-outs/sorting/9)

Comment: Just from a quick glance, your `mergesort` accepts an `n` value greater than 2, and it will continue to execute so long as `n` remains greater than 2. But you recursively call `mergesort` with the same `n` value, so you get infinite recursion.

Comment: so what should i do sir?

Comment: Try to fix your code logic. Why are you calling `mergesort` with the same value?

Comment: what do you mean by same value sir?

Comment: No need to call me sir :), and what I mean is, look at the line `mergesort(right,n-mid,n);`.. Your third parameter doesn't change in the recursive call (leading to infinite recursion). You're either recursively calling your function wrong, or `if(n<2) return;` isn't sufficient to stop the recursion.

Comment: okies;) can u post the right pgm if u can..

Comment: `for(i=mid+1;i<n;i++){
        right[i]=a[i];
    }` goes up to `i=n-1`, but `right` is declared as `int mid=(s+n)/2;
int left[mid],right[n-mid];` : `right` is too small and it can trigger undefined behavior, such as a segmentation fault and a premature termination.

Comment: @francis how can i avoid this mistake?

Comment: Add other index, something like `int j=0;for(i=mid+1;i<n;i++){ right[j]=a[i]; j++; }` and do the same for array `left`. The calls to `mergesort()` will have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: i tried it...it still is not wrking :(

Comment: Have you changed the calls to `mergesort()` ? Something like `mergesort(left,0,mid-s);
    mergesort(right,0,n-mid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in comments, `for(i=mid+1;i<n;i++){ right[i]=a[i]; }` goes up to `i=n-1`, but `right` is declared as `int mid=(s+n)/2; int left[mid],right[n-mid];` : `right` is too small and it can trigger undefined behavior, such as a segmentation fault and a premature termination.

To overcome this problem, another index `j` is introduced :`int j=0;for(i=mid+1;i<n;i++){ right[j]=a[i]; j++; }` and the same  is done for array `left`. The calls to `mergesort()` have to be changed accordingly :

```
        mergesort(left,mid);
        mergesort(right,n-mid);
```

The second argument `s` has been removed. It could be re-introduced later to avoid unnecessary copies and reduce memory footprint.

The extra little issue was `int a[]={9,8,7,5,1,2,4,3,6},i;...for(i=0;i<10;i++)` : `a` has 9 items and the for loop tries to access the tenth item `a[9]`.

Here is a corrected code that delivers the expected output. Compile it with `gcc main.c -o main`

```
#include<stdio.h>
void merge(int a[],int left[],int l,int right[],int r){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<l&&j<r){
        if(left[i]<=right[j]){
            a[k]=left[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            a[k]=right[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<l){
        a[k]=left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j<r){
        a[k]=right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
void mergesort(int a[],int n){
    int i;
    int mid=(n)/2;
    int left[mid],right[n-mid];

    if(n<2) return;

    else{
        int j=0;
        for(i=0;i<mid;i++){
            left[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        for(i=mid;i<n;i++){
            right[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        mergesort(left,mid);
        mergesort(right,n-mid);
        merge(a,left,mid,right,n-mid);
    }
}
int main(int argv,char*argc){
    int a[]={9,8,7,5,1,2,4,3,6},i;
    printf("sorting....\n");
    mergesort(a,9);
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){

        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this implementation of `mergesort` method uses `n*log2(n)` time to complete, which is OK, but also `n* log2(n)*sizeof int` bytes of stack space!  A potentially huge amount of memory, likely to exceed available stack space.  Furthermore, it is impossible to detect such stack overflow gracefully.  I recommend using a single temporary array allocated with `malloc`, and a more efficient sorting algorithm such as radix sort, appropriate for your problem and much faster for medium to large values of `n`.

Comment: @chqrlie : This implementation is clearly limited... It just solves the asker's problem but it can't handle large arrays. In this case, the best way to go is to use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)